# Is it possible to initialize React Final Form from a saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, react-final-form, final-form

I'm migrating from Redux Form to React Final Form on a project that's using React and redux-saga. A common pattern for initializing forms in the project looks like this:

```
import { initialize } from "redux-form";
import { call } from "redux-saga/effects";
// ...
    const data = yield call(axios.get, "/backend/api/endpoint");
    yield initialize("someFormName", data);
// ...
```

Is there a way to do something similar for Final Form?

Creating an object in the store, setting it from the saga and passing it to Final Form's `initialValues` prop works, but I suspect it's not the optimal solution, and I'd rather not create a store for every single form in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get your initial values all the way into the `initialValues` prop of `<Form/>`, then yes. How you `connect()` up your component to do so is up to you.